# Is bufferbloat caused by low upstream

Tags: networking, router, bufferbloat

Right now I have ADSL2+ connection at my home, and an old router that doesn't support any SQM algorithms. This is limitations of my internet set by ISP :

[image]

I can't do video calls at all and suffer playing video games.

I think the problem is caused by low upstream limitations, but can router with SQM algorithms improve this situation considering limitations set by my ISP?

Also my bufferbloat test:

[Bufferbloat test full link](https://www.waveform.com/tools/bufferbloat?test-id=6ed96ee7-f376-4aa4-8c4a-95b21754118a)

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Even if you fix the bufferbloat, your line is still far too slow to use for video calling.

Comment: Bufferbloat is caused when more data packets are queued up waiting to go out than can be sent in the time needed. It happening while you are downloading suggests that the ratio of your download to upload speeds is unsuitable. The only people who can fix that is your ISP.

Comment: Possible dupe https://superuser.com/questions/1324956/is-bufferbloat-triggered-on-a-certain-speed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... but can router with SQM algorithms improve this situation considering limitations set by my ISP?

YES! Before I moved, I had 7mbps/768kbps DSL service, and an IQrouter was a simple, clear solution. It was never "fast", but I could sustain two zoom calls (me and my wife) quite nicely.

IQrouter is easy to set up, and will almost certainly solve the problem. (If it doesn't, you can always return it to Amazon, but you won't want to...)

**Update:** To answer your question: No, low upstream speeds don't *cause* bufferbloat. It's your router (DSL modem) that is blissfully unaware of how much data it has queued to send over a low-speed link. IQrouter uses the SQM algorithm to take control of queueing/buffering so there's "just enough" data to keep the pipe full without adding delay. I'm proud of my [Best Bufferbloat Analogy](https://randomneuronsfiring.com/best-bufferbloat-analogy-ever/) that explains how SQM works...

Answer (score 1):

Your download speed is passable, but your upload speed
is much too low.
You need to ask your ISP for a higher-speed line (and modem).

For example,
[Zoom bandwidth requirements](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/201362023-Zoom-system-requirements-Windows-macOS-Linux)
are:

> - For 1:1 video calling:
>
>   - For high-quality video: 600kbps (up/down)
>   - For 720p HD video: 1.2Mbps (up/down)
>   - For 1080p HD video: 3.8Mbps/3.0Mbps (up/down)
> - For group video calling:
>
>   - For high-quality video: 1.0 Mbps/600kbps (up/down)
>   - For 720p HD video: 2.6Mbps/1.8Mbps (up/down)
>   - For 1080p HD video: 3.8Mbps/3.0Mbps (up/down)
>   - For gallery view receiving: 2.0Mbps (25 views), 4.0Mbps (49 views)

Answer (score 0):

Your speeds are bottom line passible for video calling but 2.5 seconds of bufferbloat need to get fixed by an sqm capable router. Even the lowest end router from gl.inet for 20 bucks will improve your experience